# Eviews can't export to Excel when print titles are defined

Tags: excel, eviews

We want to save time when exporting to Excel from Eviews. To do this we have export a long list of variables in one command. Totally almost 800 rows are exported at once. We want to have titles on top of each page. To be readable we have at most about 70 rows per page. We can not put titles on the rows that are on top of the page, because then the titles would be written over by Eviews, so we use the Print titles options in Excel.

The problem is that when we use Print titles we get an error we do not get otherwise, and afterwards the excel file looses all old data.

```
The name cannot be the same as a built in name.
Old name: Print_Titles
```

Is there a way to get around this?

**EDIT:** Depending on how print_titles are stored in the xlsx-file, the file can either get overwritten or only the print titles get "removed". When unzipping the xlsx-file and reading an xml I get this row:

```
<definedName name="_xlnm.Print_Titles" localSheetId="0">MySheet!$1:$1</definedName>
```

if I do the same after export _xlnm. is removed and I get this:

```
<definedName name="Print_Titles" localSheetId="0">MySheet!$1:$1</definedName>
```

And then the print titles don't work and has to be reset manually again.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in either excel or eviews. After lots of contact with people at Eviews, we got a workaround, that is using excel 2003 file format. Then print titles are not removed.